# BIND/Linux limiting concurrent UDP connections

Tags: linux, bind

I'm seeing an issue where the number of concurrent UDP connections to BIND appears to be getting limited. I've previously increased `recursive-clients` in `named.conf` and I've increased the socket limit in `/etc/sysconfig/named`:

```
ulimit -HSn 16384
OPTIONS="-S 16384"
```

I'm no longer seeing any errors in the logs, but I'm still getting slow/lost responses to DNS queries. Looking at `netstat -an` or in `/proc/net/udp` I can see that the number of UDP connections is constantly just under 4096, which suggests to me that I'm hitting a limit somewhere that I can't identify. I can see tens of thousands of `[UNREPLIED]` entries in `/proc/net/nf_conntrack`, so I'm assuming that the connections are getting through iptables but not getting accepted by BIND.

I'm seeing this on multiple CentOS 6.5 servers running stock BIND 9.8.2 in a VMWare VM (different physical hosts). Customer-facing IP's are loopbacks advertised via AnyCast; if I query a server's actual IP I consistently get an instant response, so it's possible that the limit is per-local-IP.

Can anyone suggest any limits I might be hitting, or anything else I'm missing?